# Threading Hanging Indefinitely

Tags: python, multithreading

I was reading about `Queue` in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) and [this book](https://pymotw.com/3/queue/#building-a-threaded-podcast-client), and I don't fully understand why my thread hangs. I have the following [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
from threading import Thread
import queue


def print_number(number_queue_display):

    while True:
        number = number_queue_display.get()
        print(number)
        number_queue_display.task_done()


number_queue = queue.Queue()
printing_numbers = Thread(target=print_number, args=(number_queue,),)
printing_numbers.start()

number_queue.put(5)
number_queue.put(10)
number_queue.put(15)
number_queue.put(20)

number_queue.join()
printing_numbers.join()
```

The only time it works is if I set the thread to daemon like so:

```
printing_numbers.setDaemon(True)
```

but that's because as stated in the Python documentation, [the program will exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) when only the daemon threads are left. The Python docs example for `Queue` doesn't use a daemon thread.

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
>   flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
>   are left.

Even if I were to remove the two joins(`number_queue.join()` `printing_numbers.join()`), it still hangs, but I'm unsure of why.

**Questions:**

1. Why is it hanging?
2. How do I keep it as a non-daemon thread, but prevent it from hanging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_number()` is running an infinite loop - it never exits, so the thread never ends.  It sits in `number_queue_display.get()` forever, waiting for another queue item that never appears.  Then, since the thread never ends, `printing_numbers.join()` also waits forever.

So you need *some* way to tell the thread to quit.  One common way is to put a special "sentinel" value on the queue, and have the thread exit when it sees that.  For concreteness, here's a complete program, which is very much the same as what you started with.  `None` is used as the sentinel (and is commonly used for this purpose), but any unique object would work.  Note that the `.task_done()` parts were removed, because they no longer serve a purpose.

```
from threading import Thread
import queue

def print_number(number_queue_display):

    while True:
        number = number_queue_display.get()
        if number is None:
            break
        print(number)


number_queue = queue.Queue()
printing_numbers = Thread(target=print_number, args=(number_queue,),)
printing_numbers.start()

number_queue.put(5)
number_queue.put(10)
number_queue.put(15)
number_queue.put(20)
number_queue.put(None)  # tell the thread it's done

printing_numbers.join() # wait for the thread to exit
```